Raman spectra gaussian widening
I am trying to correct for the Gaussian widening in my Raman spectra due to the optical distortion and the incoming laser beam not being perfectly collimated. My approach is to take a Raman spectrum of a HeNe bulb which should have a much narrower width than the Gaussian widening to use as a reference for determining the Gaussian correction. My question is, which line(s) in the spectrum can/ should be used?
So far I have just been using lines with high signal-to-noise ratio and relatively flat shoulders. Which has provided Gaussian widening that is in agreement with sample Voigt fits.
Attached is the spectrum of the HeNe bulb.

